# MutationOberserver should observe iframes

Tags: javascript, jquery

Currently I use an observer to attach a click event as the first event handler for dynamically created elements. Unfortunately this doesn't work for elements within a dynamically created iframe.

```
elementObserver = new MutationObserver(function (mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(function (mutation) {
    $(mutation.target).bindFirst('click', my.callback.function);
  });
});

elementObserver.observe(document.body, {childList: true, subtree: true});
```

The `bindFirst()` function looks like:

```
$.fn.bindFirst = function(name, fn) {
   this.on(name, fn);
   this.each(function() {
      var handlers = $._data(this, 'events')[name.split('.')[0]];
      var handler = handlers.pop();
      handlers.splice(0, 0, handler);
   });
};
```

But `my.callback.function` won't get triggered within the iframe. How can I solve this problem so that my `my.callback.function` gets triggered in the iframe as well.

Comment: The MutationObserver only works within the DOM it was defined on. The contents of an iframe are a separate DOM and hence will not be included in any monitored mutation. Is the content of the `iframe` on the same domain as the parent window?

Comment: Yes the content of the iframe is on the same domain. Is it possible to define the MutationObserver for dynamically created iframes from the "original" DOM?